# In Javascript, why should instance variables with reference type be put in the constructor?

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

Reading an excerpt from Google developer insights: 
https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-javascript#initializing-instance-variables

---

**Place instance variable declaration/initialization on the prototype for instance variables with value type (rather than reference type) initialization values (i.e. values of type number, Boolean, null, undefined, or string). This avoids unnecessarily running the initialization code each time the constructor is called. (This can't be done for instance variables whose initial value is dependent on arguments to the constructor, or some other state at time of construction.)**

**For Example, instead of:**

```
foo.Bar = function() {
  this.prop1_ = 4;
  this.prop2_ = true;
  this.prop3_ = [];
  this.prop4_ = 'blah';
};
```

**Use:**

```
foo.Bar = function() {
  this.prop3_ = [];
};

foo.Bar.prototype.prop1_ = 4;

foo.Bar.prototype.prop2_ = true;

foo.Bar.prototype.prop4_ = 'blah';
```

---

I understand the logic behind putting variables with value type into the function prototype, but aren't we running the initialization code when we have a reference variable like this.prop3_ = []; (as per Google example)? Does this not create a new array with every invocation of the constructor?

Comment: "Does this not create a new array with every invocation of the constructor?" - it does, which is the point.

Comment: There is no "reference type" or "value type". Valid language types are listed in [*ECMA-262 §6.1*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-types). Variables have a value, the value might be a [*primitive value*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-primitive-value) or a *reference* (aka [*Reference Specification Type*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-reference-specification-type)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instance properties of reference types need to be added to the constructor otherwise when added to the prototype, each instance of the constructed object would share the same reference. It's OK when just reading information, but problem occurs when modyfing. Please check the following example

```
var Test = function () {
    this.foo = [];
};

Test.prototype.bar = [];

var instance1 = new Test();
var instance2 = new Test();

instance1.foo.push(1);
instance1.bar.push(1);
instance2.foo.push(2);
instance2.bar.push(2);

console.log(instance1.foo, instance1.bar); // [1], [1,2]
```

Although `instance1.bar.push` was called only once, the array has two values, because `instance1.bar` and `instance2.bar` are the same array, shared by two objects.